# Mass editing hyperlinks in Excel, replacing parts of the hyperlinks with data in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, hyperlink, edit

I'm not too good with Macros or VBA coding but I'd like to use it to solve this problem. I am creating a photo database for a hotel room inventory catalog. I am just using Excel to edit the hyperlinks. The situation is that each room has a specific hyperlink to it's folder of photographs. So technically, each of the line items has almost the same address, except the last few numbers which is it's destination.

For example: The room 301 will have the following hyperlink: 
http://sharepoint/sites/NYNYRoomInventoryCatalog/Rooms%20By%20Floor/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=/sites/NYNYRoomInventoryCatalog/Rooms%20By%20Floor/03/301&

Room 302 is http://sharepoint/sites/NYNYRoomInventoryCatalog/Rooms%20By%20Floor/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=/sites/NYNYRoomInventoryCatalog/Rooms%20By%20Floor/03/302&

Room 916 would be http://sharepoint/sites/NYNYRoomInventoryCatalog/Rooms%20By%20Floor/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=/sites/NYNYRoomInventoryCatalog/Rooms%20By%20Floor/09/916&

Basically, I just want to replace the 09/916& this part with whatever floor and room number the room is. I have separate columns in my Excel spreadsheet indicating what the room number is.

Column A is the hyperlink, Column B is the room number, and column C is the floor number

Is there a macros code that can generate the hyperlinks for each line item in my spreadsheet

http://sharepoint/sites/NYNYRoomInventoryCatalog/Rooms%20By%20Floor/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=/sites/NYNYRoomInventoryCatalog/Rooms%20By%20Floor/**FLOOR NUMBER**/**ROOM NUMBER**&

and the floor number and room number will be extracted from the columns. I would do it manually, but there are over 2,000 rooms. I would greatly appreciate any help or direction for this!

Answer (score 0):

In column D (starting in D2):

```
="http://sharepoint/sites/NYNYRoomInventoryCatalog/Rooms%20By%20Floor/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=/sites/NYNYRoomInventoryCatalog/Rooms%20By%20Floor/" & C2 & "/" & B2 & "&"
```

Fill down to the end of your list of data.